# Achieve chrome.infobars experience using chrome.pageAction

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome team have finally declared chrome.infobars WontFix and are removing it from the codebase (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458325).

At the moment I have an extension which injects HTML to simulate an information/error bar. However, this isn't ideal and possibly isn't a best practice either.

The chrome.infobars resource suggests using chrome.pageAction. So my question is, how can I achieve a chrome.infobars (kind of) experience using chrome.pageAction (example code would be appreciated!)? or am I actually best off just continuing to inject HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, you can't.

[`pageAction` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) only allows you to show a tiny icon in the omnibar.

While there is a programmatic way to let it show a popup window [in the works](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489), it's not currently available.

In any case, it won't integrate well in the page: it will be a pop-out rectangular window out of the icon that automatically closes if it loses focus. If you have a working HTML UI injection solution, it's best to stick with it.